# Avoid using inout in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, inout

I want to avoid using inout at the following code.

Is there any way I can do it? For example a helping signal?

```
entity LA_Unit is
    Port ( Cin : in    STD_LOGIC;
           P   : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           G   : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           C3  : out   STD_LOGIC;
           C   : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));
end LA_Unit;

architecture Behavioral of LA_Unit is
begin
  C(0) <= (P(0) and Cin) xor G(0);
  C(1) <= (P(1) and C(0)) xor G(1);
  C(2) <= (P(2) and C(1)) xor G(2);
  C3   <= (P(3) and C(2)) xor G(3);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as a "Solution" if one solved your problem.

Answer (score 6):

If the purpose is simply to provide the intermediate value of `C` as an output to the module, there are different options to avoid `inout`.

If the tools support VHDL-2008, you can simply change `inout` to `out`, and then the `C` can still be read internally.

If the tools only support VHDL-2002, then you can still change the `inout` to `out`, but you then need an internal signal like:

```
architecture Behavioral of LA_Unit is
  signal C_int : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  C_int(0) <= (P(0) and Cin) xor G(0);
  C_int(1) <= (P(1) and C_int(0)) xor G(1);
  C_int(2) <= (P(2) and C_int(1)) xor G(2);
  C3       <= (P(3) and C_int(2)) xor G(3);
  C        <= C_int;
end Behavioral;
```

As xvan also write, only use `inout` for toplevel ports on the chip, or for special test-bench use, since `inout` are not supported internally in a chip.

Answer (score 4):

Use a signal as an intermediate for C(0) and C(1).

Inouts should only be used for hardware io ports, like a gpio port, or the data port on a memory bus.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Using buffer mode instead of inout.

   ```
   entity LA_Unit is
       Port ( Cin : in   STD_LOGIC;
              P : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              G  : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              C3 : out   STD_LOGIC;
              C   : buffer  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));
   end LA_Unit;

   architecture Behavioral of LA_Unit is
   begin
     C(0) <= (P(0) and Cin) xor G(0);
     C(1) <= (P(1) and C(0)) xor G(1);
     C(2) <= (P(2) and C(1)) xor G(2);
     C3   <= (P(3) and C(2)) xor G(3);
   end Behavioral;
   ```

   Some tools have problems with this mode.
2. An intermediate signal:

   ```
   entity LA_Unit is
       Port ( Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
              P : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              G  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              C3 : out  STD_LOGIC;
              C   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0)
     );
   end entity;

   architecture rtl of LA_Unit is
     signal C_i : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
   begin
     C_i(0) <= (P(0) and Cin) xor G(0);
     C_i(1) <= (P(1) and C_i(0)) xor G(1);
     C_i(2) <= (P(2) and C_i(1)) xor G(2);
     C_i(3) <= (P(3) and C_i(2)) xor G(3);
     C  <= C_i(2 downto 0);
     C3 <= C_i(3);
   end architecture
   ```

Comment: The port `C` should have mode `out` in the second example.

Comment: @MartinZabel Fixed it :).